# Clickhouse table TTL does not remove old records

Tags: clickhouse

I have added a TTL to this `GraphiteMergeTree` table, but old records are not being removed automatically.

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.graphite_data
(
    `Path` String,
    `Value` Float64,
    `Time` UInt32,
    `Date` Date,
    `Timestamp` UInt32
)
ENGINE = GraphiteMergeTree('graphite_rollup')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(Date)
ORDER BY (Path, Time)
TTL Date + toIntervalQuarter(2)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

I still see old data in this table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM graphite_data
LIMIT 10

┌─Path─────────────────────────────┬─Value─┬───────Time─┬───────Date─┬──Timestamp─┐
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577833200 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577836784 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577836800 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577840384 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577840400 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577843984 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577844000 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577847584 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577847600 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577851184 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577851200 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577854784 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577854800 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577858384 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577858400 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577861984 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577862000 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577865584 │
│ carbon.agents.test.pickle.active │     0 │ 1577865600 │ 2020-01-01 │ 1577869184 │
└──────────────────────────────────┴───────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘

10 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.029 sec.
```

I also did `OPTIMIZE FINAL`, but the result is still the same. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TTL is not immediate. It's eventual.

Try `ALTER TABLE default.graphite_data MATERIALIZE TTL`

Comment: What does that exactly do?

Comment: It applies TTL rules immediately.

Comment: TTL -- rewrites data on the disk without expired rows once a day https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#mergetree-query-clauses 

merge_with_ttl_timeout — Minimum delay in seconds before repeating a merge with TTL. Default value: 86400 (1 day).

Comment: That is weird, it worked. Although the TTL was set already months ago. When would it be picking that up?

Comment: It's expected. What do you mean by "TTL was set already months ago" ? It was added by ALTER ? Or it was initially in "CREATE TABLE" ?

Comment: It was indeed added by ALTER months ago. So when should that be taken into account?

Comment: probably you use old version of CH. This version does't apply TTL automatically to parts created before ALTER, and it needs ` ALTER TABLE MATERIALIZE TTL`